# pythonnet in linux cannot import ssl

Tags: python, ubuntu, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python.net

i'm trying to run python scripts from .net using pythonnet in ubuntu (wsl). but when `import ssl`, I got the following error

```
Python.Runtime.PythonException: ModuleNotFoundError : No module named '_ssl'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
```

but I have openssl installed. running the following from python

```
import ssl
ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
```

correctly returned `'OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020'`

i've tried adding "/lib:/usr/lib" to both PYTHONPATH env and `PythonEngine.PythonPath`
but it still cannot locate _ssl.so from within pythonnet

Answer (score 1):

found the issue.
I need to add `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload` to `PythonEngine.PythonPath`. somehow
adding only `/usr/local/lib/python3.8` is not enough.

so I ended up having to list all of these `/usr/local/lib/python3.8:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` to make it work

not sure what the traversing logic to resolve python module used by python.net is. if anyone have explanation for this please post an answer